# 2013 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

This is an alternative form of the Town Hall Chat system we've done [in previous elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169754/february-2013-stack-overflow-moderator-election-town-hall-chat), we're trying some new things to test out how a different approach works.

This thread's purpose was to collect questions for the Q&A, which I'm happy to say we've chosen all of the provided questions. You can find the actual Q&A here: [2013 Moderator Election Q&A](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3877/2013-moderator-election-qa)

Here's how it'll work.

- For the first 48 hours after the nomination phase ends in the election (so, until March 27th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions (which I will include as an answer) of our own. These are mostly drawn from previous Town Hall Chats that we have run, questions that are asked very often.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- After the 48 hours are completed, this question will be closed from further submissions of questions. We will review the questions that were submitted and select some portion of them to present alongside our general questions as a new Q&A thread which moderator candidates will be posting their answers.

If you have any questions or feedback about this new process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: @jrista Off topic: Just got a notification to cast vote in Election, but why are there no votes in Primary phase ? http://photo.stackexchange.com/election/3?tab=primary

Comment: There's no primary phase if there are 10 or fewer candidates in the nomination phase. Primary phase is around to knock down the candidate pool to 10.

Comment: Awesome idea, looking forward to responding to the community's questions.

Comment: Just wanted to double check if this is still happening or not.

Comment: @AJHenderson It is. Unfortunately, I got somewhat distracted last night and didn't quite get to close these. Let me wrap this up now, then.

Answer (score 4):

What is your general ideology regarding how moderation should be performed?

What are your thoughts on the community-driven nature of StackExchange, and would you support continued moderation primarily by community members?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election.

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?
- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Answer (score 3):

Is there anything about Photo-SE which you would like to be significantly different from the way it is now?

Answer (score 1):

What is your motivation for being a moderator?  What makes it something you want to do?  Why do you feel like photography is the right community for moderating?

Comment: Not sure if it's good form to submit a question myself as a candidate, but I think this one would give valuable insight in to how much staying power candidates have.